# Subdomain security in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy, security

Let's say I'm trying to create an application called Blue. Blue is a Ruby on Rails application that turns the background of any website blue. It also allows users to log in and keep track of the websites they've visited and turned blue.

In order to turn a website's background websites blue, I've created a web proxy that inserts `<link HREF="http://www.example.com/blue.css" type="text/css">` into the response's body. The proxy is implemented as a rack application and is be placed inside the Rails routes using the approach from the [Rack in Rails 3 Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/222-rack-in-rails-3?view=asciicast):

```
root :to => BlueProxy, :constraints => { :subdomain => "proxy" }
```

I'm very concerned about security with this approach. I know by default the domain for the cookies in my application would be `.example.com`. If the user typed in a malicious URL, the website could manipulate the user's account. I could fix this by only allowing the `www` subdomain for cookies in the application. However, I'd also like the proxy to be able to store cookies for the proxied site as well.

Here are my three questions:

1. Is this a bad approach? Is there a better way to solve this problem?
2. What's the best way to keep sibling subdomain cookies separate in Rails?
3. Are there any other security concerns I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is dangerous, and I caution you against running a proxy for several reasons:

1. It brings up a host of legal issues ranging from people accessing illegal content to your hosting content for your own benefit (and modifying it).
2. Your bandwidth (and hosting fees) will explode if the site gets popular.
3. Loading content inside an iframe has ux issues, like the browser back button not quite performing as the user wants it to.
4. Running a proxy opens up several more attack vectors to your site (e.g. sending a permalink to a malicious site proxied through your site) that you'll have to consider from a security perspective.

Instead of running an open proxy (okay, maybe it's not completely open, but how hard is it for someone to sign up?) on your back end, consider using a browser extension or greasemonkey script on the front end that can get its set of rules from your rails app and then add the stylesheet changes on the client side.

Comment: These are all great points.

1. I thought proxies were covered under the safe harbor provisions in the DMCA. Do you know if there are any issues with modifying the content (i.e. turning the background blue) when that's the intended use of the site?
2. Is there some way I could use a non-blocking event-based server to mitigate this? That way I could handle incoming requests while waiting on external servers to serve their pages. 3. I was going to implement a JavaScript solution to keep the browser history in sync with the iframe content.
4. Could you point me to any good resources for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, a browser extension or a greasemonkey script aren't viable options for my project. It needs to work across all modern browsers and the most popular mobile devices.

Comment: Personally, I would prioritize it working over it working in every modern browser/appliance. By far the easiest solution is an extension, so why not do that for one browser for your MVP, to validate the value that it provides, and then decide if the best path forward is multiple extensions/apps, or a proxy solution? To answer the other questions, you can mitigate the legal and load implications, but you'll have to be very creative to mitigate the bandwidth and cost issues, and it'll be an uphill battle. Look at LastPass for an example of a successful extension solution.